# How to pass an undefined value to jest.expect?

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I'm coding on a TS project with `strictNullChecks`.
I want to make sure that the result of a function is undefined:

```
const company = await getRepository(Company).findOne({ id: deletedID });
expect(company).toBeUndefined();
       ^^^^^^^
```

However, ESLint gives me this warning on the expect line: `Passing nullable argument to function that expects non nullable`.

I could also do `expect(company === undefined).toBe(true)` but is there a way to use `.toBeUndefined()`?

Comment: `.toEqual(undefined)` ?

Comment: That doesn't solve the issue. I've edited the question to show you where the warning is exactly.

Comment: Have you tried `expect(company as any).toBeUndefined();`?

Comment: Yes that works.

Comment: @Gpack so is that the answer you were looking for or something else?

Comment: Yes I guess so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`as`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) like this:

```
expect(company as any).toBeUndefined();
```